# node js .10 fs.createReadStream streams2 end event not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs

I'm using Node.js v0.10.26, and trying to use the new stream2 apis http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/, 
in particular the Readable api, http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable

but the 'end' event never gets called and I can't figure out why.  wich I think is why my downstream Transform streams component aren't calling Their _flush, finish,close events,

```
var rqt = fs.createReadStream('some.csv.gz');

//readable
rqt.on('readable',  function () { console.log('readable!');  })
    .on('data',  function (data) { console.log('Data!', data);  })
    .on('error', function (err)  { console.error('Error', err);/* READ if there was an error receiving data. */ })
    .on('end',   function ()     { console.log('All done!');   /* READ fires when no more data will be provided. */ })
    .on('finish',   function ()     { console.log('All Finished!');  /*WRITEABLE */  })
    .on('close',   function ()     { console.log('close!'); /*WRITEABLE not all streams emit this*/   })
```

### Outputs:

```
readable
readable
Data 
readable
readable
Data
readable
```

---

UPDATE
the real goal of this is to do a stream like so:

```
rqt.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(csvp).on('finish',function(line){
    console.log("Finished Parsing " + csvp.records + ' ' + line);
});
```

which doesn tuse the classic mode at all,
Functionally which loads a gzipped csv, parses the csv and shows how many were found. The loading, unzip and parsing all work fine.

however none of the following get called:
 - the _flush of csvp never gets called 
 - the on('finish' event

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you solve it somehow? accepted answer doesn't seem to help

Comment: streams are like a firehose going through a pipe, if you are in flowing mode, if you have enough input, you have to drain it ..else it will get backed up and never finish.  This is to protect against memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the flowing mode and non-flowing mode APIs a bit. From the docs:

> Note that the end event will not fire unless the data is completely consumed. This can be done by switching into flowing mode, or by calling read() repeatedly until you get to the end.

Simplest fix to your snippet above is just to remove the 'readable' binding then you should be in regular flowing mode and 'data' events will fire until the stream is empty then 'end' will fire.

Comment: or I've found adding a call to read like so

    rqt.on('readable',  function () { console.log('readable!');rqt.read();  })

Comment: I knew about this, but nonetheless his code works for me on v0.10.26 and I get the output he's expecting.

Comment: hmm actuallly I tried your suggestion of removing the .on("readable" and it didn't work for me

Comment: Yeah I haven't tested it for the exact details, but I'm pretty sure the basic issue is buffered data expecting you to call `read`. If you get the right combination of event bindings, flowing/non-flowing mode, and method calls, all should be well but you can't just bind all the events and call all the methods willy-nilly.

Comment: Listening for 'readable' first enables streams2 mode, but then the following 'data' event handler switches it so streams1 mode thereafter. It doesn't try to switch back to streams2 after that with the original code.

Comment: If one of you digs in enough to work out the specifics, just post an answer. I just wanted to quickly point in the right direction.